# Why is Go adding bytes to my string?

Tags: string, utf-8, go, arrays

When I add a single byte to my string at 0x80 or above, golang will add 0xc2 before my byte.
I think this has something to do with [utf8 runes](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/). Either way, how do I just add 0x80 to the end of my string?

Example:

```
var s string = ""
len(s) // this will be 0
s += string(0x80)
len(s) // this will be 2, string is now bytes 0xc2 0x80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The From the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type):

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer.

The expression string(0x80) evaluates to a string with the UTF-8 representation of 0x80, not a string containing  the single byte 0x80. The UTF-8 representation of 0x80 is 0xc2 0x80.

Use the \x hex escape to specify the byte 0x80 in a string:

```
 s += "\x80"
```

You can create a string from an arbitrary sequence of bytes using the string([]byte) conversion.

```
 s += string([]byte{0x80})
```

Comment: But how can I add just the pure byte, if I don't know what the byte will be?

Comment: `b := byte(0x80); s += string([]byte{b})`

Comment: Better yet don't use a non-mutable type (`string`) for something mutable. If you're adding bytes to a thing you probably want the thing to be a `[]byte` or a `*bytes.Buffer` or some-such. Especially if you're using `+=` a lot as each time it may need to allocate and re-copy the string.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to avoid adding that character, if I use `string(0x80)` to convert the byte. However, I did find that if I change the whole string to a slice of bytes, then add the byte, then switch back to a string, I can get the correct byte order in the string.

Example:

```
bytearray := []byte(some_string)
bytearray = append(bytearray, 0x80)
some_string = string(bytearray)
```

Kind of a silly work around, if anyone finds a better method, please post it.